# Clear drawn shapes in a form on button click

Tags: c#

I want to clear the before drawn shape on forms in when I click a button that shape will clear. So I use codes in form:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    System.Drawing.Pen myPe = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
    Point[] array = { new Point(220, 70), new Point(200, 120), new Point(230, 120) };
    g.DrawPolygon(myPe ,array);
}
```

and I used a code below in `button1_Click`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    g.Clear(this.BackColor);  
}
```

This code and this.refresh but not working. What should I do.

Comment: You should paint from the `OnPaint` method, not from a button.

Comment: You are drawing all wrong. Which maybe good as you now can clear all the drawn pixels by minimizing and maximizing the form ;-) - Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: could you please check it..

Comment: You need to hold the data you use for drawing in a class level variable. In the clear button you can clear it. Now it is always created in the Paint event so it always reappears..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hold the data you use for drawing in a class level variable.

In the clear button you can clear it.

As it is now it is always created in the `Paint` event so it always reappears..

Using a `List<Point>` makes life a lot easier..

In the `Paint` event you can and should use the `e.Graphics` object, which is current.

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>() 

private void buttonSetDrawing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    points = new List<Point>() { new Point(220, 70), 
                                new Point(200, 120), new Point(230, 120) };
    Invalidate();
}

private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    points.Clear();
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
    if (points.Count > 1) g.DrawPolygon(myPen, points.ToArray() );
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Did you change its type from array to `List<Point>` ?? Probably not or else you would have hit an error in the DrawPolygon call, which expects an array. I have fixed that. And actually it would be a good idea to change the name as well, maybe to  `points` or `pointList`.. I'll update the answer .. __Good names are very important__ !!

Comment: Arrays are rather poor objects; they don't have a `Clear` function or most of the other nice methods the modern generics have. They also have to be preallocated to a certain size. That is very unpractical. So __you really should consider using List<T> instead__! if you really want to, you will have to write maybe  `array = new Point[] { };`instead of `point.Clear();`; change the check to test `array.Length` then! But with a list you can do so much more. e.g. you can always write `pointList.Add(new Point(...);` So much nicer!